# Problem selecting/deselecting points from Instance on Points

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances, select

I'm trying to deselect the last point from instancing.

I'm using the `Endpoint Selection` < `Boolean Math - Not` setup as I've found online, however it is used with just a direct `Curve Resample` < `Instance on Points` connection, and not with a `Curve to Points` in-between, which I need for the rotation value - but it makes the deselection not function.

How to make it work with a `Curve to Points` before?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Simple capture the endpoint selection with `Capture Attribute` before the `Curve to Points` node.

Comment: Thank you so much once again @quellenform! I've added an answer with your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### SOLUTION

### Thanks to @quellenform

Capture the `Endpoint Selection` with `Capture Attribute` before the `Curve to Points`.

[image]